# Adding an additional textbox to each row of gridview asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, gridview, textbox

I have a gridview which I am populating via an XML string. I would like to add a blank textbox to each row of this gridview to enter a value between 0 and 100. The final information, including the value we put into the textbox should be committed to the db.

Here are the code details:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">

    </asp:GridView>
```

The following code runs in the back-end to populate the gridview

```
string strXML = objwebservice.selectAllTeammembers(strteam);

        XElement xmlteam = XElement.Parse(strXML);

        var query = from c in xmlteam.Elements("team")
                    select new
                    {
                        UserName = c.Element("username").Value,
                        TeamMemberName = c.Element("name").Value

                    };

        GridView1.DataSource = query;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

So my gridview gets populated by the usernames and the teammembernames, as shown above. I want to add another column to this gridview with a textbox, and this column should be at the very end. I already tried itemtemplate field in the design section but it did not work.
As I mentioned earlier, after i put the values in the textboxes (only between 0 and 100), all the data should go to the db. This should be done at the click of a separate submit button outside the gridview. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank You

Comment: look at overriding the gridview databound event... you can use it to add a column t every row, and fill it with whatever you want.

Comment: To add onto @MaxOvrdrv, you can even change the columns to templatefields and format anyway you want as well.

Comment: this [Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178294.ASPX) is for drop down lists, but the principle is the same.

Comment: Another [Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479353.aspx) of gridview templates